# Gettings ADS as a feed in the Ionic mobile App

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, admob, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-admob

I am using **Google admob** for getting ads in the mobile app built with IONIC, but the Google ads comes at the bottom of the page as the banner, I want them as the feeds or in the list format in the app. Please help me out.

Comment: Read https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287, it's normally not supported and could incur in policy violation

Comment: Instead of Google AdMob, Is there any other option available?

Comment: we can use facebook native ads, this is shown up as a card in our app, which will not distract the user